# After intalling RabbitVCS in 12.04 , can't find the RabbitVCS menu

Tags: rabbitvcs

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I installed RabbitVCS following the steps mentioned in the link below.

http://linuxdrops.com/install-rabbitvcs-svn-git-client-on-ubuntu-12-1012-0411-1011-04/

However after restart, i am not getting the RabbitVCS menu if I right click any folder.

I have read lot of articles, everyone seems to be using it without any issues. 
Why only I am facing the problem.

I am new to Linux. Anyone please guide me. I want to use RabbitVCS since the features are too good.

Comment: Executing the following commands helped:sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/libsvn_client-1.so.0.0.0 /usr/lib/libsvn_client-1.so.1 
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/libsvn_diff-1.so.0.0.0 /usr/lib/libsvn_diff-1.so.1 
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/libsvn_repos-1.so.0.0.0 /usr/lib/libsvn_repos-1.so.1